# BadValueError: Expected bool

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

My form element is a checkbox as such:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="opt_in">
```

The property is defined in the model as follows:

```
patient_optin = ndb.BooleanProperty()
```

When I run the code on AppEngine(local) and try to put to the datastore I get this error:

```
BadValueError: Expected bool, got u'on'
```

Do I need to convert this value some how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to convert the string to a boolean.

Try this:

```
patient.patient_optin = self.request.POST.get('opt_in') == 'on'
```

Comment: but wouldn't that just set it to 'on', what if the person clicks the checkbox to 'off'? Also what if I want it to use the values yes/no or something else other than on/off

Comment: If the value that the person chooses is `'off'` then the *comparison* `self.request.POST['opt_in'] == 'on'` will be `False`. The *comparison* will not set anything to `'on'` only `True` or `False`.

Comment: Ok I tried that and got the error from appengine : 
opt_in = self.request.get("opt_in") == on
NameError: global name 'on' is not defined

Comment: That's because you didn't put quotes around `on`.

Comment: Sorry, it works now thank you :) I forgot the quote marks around 'on'.